# Can I do a peep operation at any position in stack using linkedlist in the c language?

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, singly-linked-list

All my stack operations are working well except peep operation at any given position. My code is terminating automatically.Please check my code.

```
void peep()
{
    if (top==NULL)
        printf ("stack is empty.\n");
    else
    {
        int pos,count=0;
        struct node *curr=top;
        while (curr!=NULL)
        {
            count++;
            curr=curr->link;
        }
        printf ("Enter position to view=");
        scanf ("%d",pos);
        if (pos<1 || pos>count)
            printf ("Invalid Position.\n");
        else
        {
            curr=top;
            while (pos--)
            {
                curr=curr->link;
            }
            printf ("%d\n",curr->data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and step thru it to trace what it is done and where it starts going wrong. A debugger will also instantly tell you exactly which line of code is terminating the program. If you still need further help please post a complete [mre].

Comment: `while (pos--)` should be `while (--pos)`. Better still, you don't need two `while` loops. Just have a single loop that stops when it gets up to `pos` iterations or if the end of the list is reached first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them. Like telling us the output you get and the input you give.

Comment: @kaylum You should probably write that as an answer, also explaining what happens with the code in the question now.

Comment: check return value of scanf, and because you need to write in the argument, you need to pass a pointer which could help with your code

Comment: @hyde If I were to write an answer I would need to be sure that that solves the problem and that there aren't any other issues that I haven't spotted. By running it with the issue fixed. But I can't easily do that without complete code so I don't want to spend time doing that.

Comment: Your compiler is very capable of issuing warnings about things that might not seem right. If the code you show doesn't lead to any warnings, then please enable more warnings. With GCC or Clang build with `-Wall -Wextra`, with MSVC build with `/W4`. And treat all warnings as errors that must be fixed.

Comment: And for future questions, besides reading the help pages to help you write better questions, make sure the question title is a summary or single sentence description of the problems you actually have. The question in your title is really unrelated to the problem you're having.

Comment: @kaylum Well, if you care about how the site should be used, you should not write answers in comments, because they can't be commented on easily, or voted on or marked as accepted. But yeah, I'm also guilty of answering in comments way too often, so...

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` take target variable as pointer as the function need to write to them

so you should probably write

```
scanf ("%d", &pos);
```

As it is your code would use the value stored at the memory location during the execution of the program, which should be unpredictable

Note that you should also check the return value of scanf as it would also help you understand when it fails.